# Syntax Error Mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

When new user registered automatically its permissionID will be 1. It's just that simple, but mysql syntax errors are killing me. Please help

```
CREATE TRIGGER `user_default_role` 
AFTER INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE @userID int;
SET @userID = (SELECT userID FROM inserted LIMIT 1);
INSERT INTO `user_permission` (`userID`,`permissionID`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (@userID,1 ,NOW(),null);
END
```

This is the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@userID int' at line 5
```

**EDIT**: I didn't know about `DELIMETER` and `NEW` instead of `inserted`. Thank you for all who responded so quickly. Here is the updated code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_default_role` AFTER INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `user_permission` (`userID`, `permissionID`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
        VALUES (new.userID, 1, NOW(), null);
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do you have a `delimiter` statement before the `create trigger`?  Do you have a table called `inserted`?  That looks suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inserted` is something from SQL Server, but otherwise your syntax really does suggest MySQL.  This may work for you:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `user_default_role` AFTER INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `user_permission` (`userID`, `permissionID`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
        VALUES (new.userId, 1, NOW(), null);
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting syntax error because of following the reasons:

1- Missing Delimiters.

2- Session variable(starting from @) cannot be declared.you can directly set the values to them.

3- There is no inserted table in MySQL where triggers temporary inserts data.You can access inserted values using `NEW`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_default_role` 
AFTER INSERT ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    SET @userID =NEW.userID;
    INSERT INTO `user_permission` (`userID`,`permissionID`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (@userID,1 ,NOW(),null);
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```